# HighCharts - hide date on x-axis and have only hours and minutes

Tags: highcharts

How is it possible to hide date on x-axis with datetime, and leave only hours and minutes?

For example in the below graph I would like to have `00:00` instead of `19. Dec`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution from https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/highcharts-hide-date-on-x-axis-and-have-only-hours-t39998/

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.dateFormat("%H:%M", this.value);
    }
  }
},
```